# Find the distance travelled by an ant in the coordinate plane

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> An ant is standing on the origin. It begins by walking 1 unit in the positive $x$-direction and then turns $45$ degrees counterclockwise and walks $\dfrac{1}{2}$ units in that direction. The ant then turns another $45$ degrees and walks $\dfrac{1}{3}$ units in that direction. The ant keeps doing this endlessly. How far is the ant's final position from the initial position?

I think I should let the origin be $(0,0)$ and calculate the coordinates of the points that ant reaches each time it turns. I believe the $x$-coordinate at the $n$th step is $\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{cos(\dfrac{\pi}{4}(k-1))}{k}$ and the $y$-coordinate at the $n$th step is $\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{sin(\dfrac{\pi}{4}(k-1))}{k}$.

Comment: How did you get that answer? Where is $n$ in that formula?

Comment: @Andrei that was a typo ok? you don't need to take things so literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is amenable to some simple complex number analysis (you have to work in radian measure, note that $45^{\circ} = \frac{\pi}{4}$).

Each step can be characterised as a vector in the complex plane. The first step is $\displaystyle 1 = 1e^{i0}$, the second is $\displaystyle \frac 12e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$, and the $n$th step is $\displaystyle \frac 1n e^{i\frac{(n-1)\pi}{4}}$. The final position is the infinite sum of all of these complex numbers.

Let $\displaystyle z = e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$.

Then define a series sum $\displaystyle S(z) = 1 + \frac 12 z + \frac 13 z^2 + \frac 14 z^3 + ...$

Note that $zS(z) = z + \frac 12 z^2 + \frac 13 z^3 + \frac 14 z^4 + ...$

And now observe: $(zS(z))' = 1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4 + ... = \frac 1{1-z}$, where convergence is assured for complex $|z| < 1$.

By integrating and rearranging, we find, $\displaystyle S(z) = - \frac 1z \ln(1-z)$. (The constant of integration is easily shown to be zero).

Now find $|\displaystyle S(e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}})|$, which is the distance of the final position of the ant from the origin.

$|\displaystyle S(e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}})| = |-e^{-\frac{i\pi}{4}}\ln(1-e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}})|$

Since $\displaystyle |z_1z_2| = |z_1||z_2|$, the above is equal to $\displaystyle |-e^{-\frac{i\pi}{4}}||\ln(1-e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}})| = |\ln(1-e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}})|$

(since $\displaystyle |-e^{-\frac{i\pi}{4}}| = 1$)

To find $\displaystyle |\ln(1-e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}})|$, we first express $\displaystyle 1-e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$  in the form $re^{i\theta}$.

$\displaystyle 1-e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}} = 1-\cos \frac{\pi}{4} - i\sin\frac{\pi}{4}$

Now $\displaystyle r = \sqrt{(1-\cos \frac{\pi}{4})^2 + (\sin\frac{\pi}{4})^2} = \sqrt{2 - 2\cos \frac{\pi}{4}} = \sqrt{2-\sqrt 2}$

and $\displaystyle \theta = \arctan{\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{4}}{1-\cos \frac{\pi}{4}}} = \arctan (\sqrt 2 + 1)$

and $\displaystyle \ln(re^{i\theta}) = \ln r + i\theta$, giving:

$\displaystyle |\ln(1-e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}})| = |\frac 12 \ln{(2-\sqrt 2)} + i\arctan{(\sqrt 2 + 1)}| \\= \sqrt{[\arctan(\sqrt 2 + 1)]^2 + \frac 14[\ln(2-\sqrt 2)]^2} \\= 1.20806...$

Comment: @Deepakyou weren’t supposed to use WolframAlpha. Usually, that should be a last resort if a problem is too difficult. I think this problem could be tackled alternatively using known integration techniques.

Comment: @fordjones This answer _does_ tackle the problem using a known integration technique (as well as some work with infinite series). The only other thing you need to do to have a complete solution without use of WA is to evaluate $|{-e}^{-{i\pi}/{4}}\ln(1-e^{i{\pi}/{4}})|$ yourself. It's not very difficult.

Comment: @DavidK is my reasoning correct here: $|-e^{-\frac{i\pi}{4}}|=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $|\ln(1-e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}})| = |\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{e^{\frac{i\pi n}{4}}}{n}|\leq|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{2}n}n}|$? But even if it were, I still don’t think this is useful. Any ideas on how I could compute $|\ln(1-e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}})|$?

Comment: I would plot the numbers on the complex plane and use polar coordinates (technically, argument and modulus). The notation $\lvert z\rvert$ is the modulus of $z,$ so anything on the unit circle ($e^{i\theta}$ for any real number $\theta$) has modulus $1.$ For the logarithm, write $z = \lvert z\rvert e^{i\theta} = e^{\ln(\lvert z\rvert)+i\theta},$ and then $\ln(z) = \ln(\lvert z\rvert)+i\theta.$

Comment: @fordjones Since I have found a bit of time, I have edited my post to include the full calculation. Hope you find this useful.